# How to add Angular forEach every item in a single array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Here i like to explain my problem clearly.

```
$http.get('arealist.json').success(function(response){
      angular.forEach(response, function(data){
           $scope.arealist = data.area_name;
           console.log($scope.arealist);
      });
});
```

Using the above code am getting area_name from arealist.json.
and it looks like below image in console.
[image: console.log image]

but i need the store above data in a array and it look like below

```
$scope.arealist = [ 
                    "Avadi", 
                    "Poonamallee",
                    "Padi", 
                    "Ambattur Industrial Estat",
                    "Annanagar",
                    "Arumbakkam",
                    "Kodambakkam",
                    "Nandanam"
                  ]
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a variable like below.

```
var arealistArray=[];
$scope.arealist=[];
```

Then push a value into array.

```
angular.forEach(response, function(data){
       arealistArray.push(data.area_name);
  });
```

Finally Assign the array to scope variable.

```
$scope.arealist=arealistArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array:

```
$scope.arealist = [];
$http.get('arealist.json').success(function(response){
      angular.forEach(response, function(data){
           $scope.arealist.push(data.area_name);
           console.log($scope.arealist);
      });
});
```

Comment: getting error as **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Comment: Have you declared $scope.arealist = [] ? See the first statement in the code snippet.

Comment: I dont think this is possible. Can you recreate the issue in a plunker/fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are performing this request within a controller (as `$scope` is available)? So first of all, you should be doing requests like this within a service. For example:

```
angular
    .module(/*module name*/)
    .service('AreaService', function ($http) {

        // Map the array of area objects to an array
        // of each area object's `area_name` property
        this.getAreas = function () {
            return $http
                .get('arealist.json')
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data.map(function (data) {
                        return data.area_name;
                    });
                });
        };
    })
```

And then consume the service within your controller:

```
    .controller(/*controller name*/, function (AreaService) {
        AreaService.getAreas().then(function (areas) {
            $scope.arealist = areas;
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Approach is good, but mistakes in code. AreaService::getAreas should not use success handler but use then handler where the response data is transformed and returned. In the controller code, service API should be consumed as a then callback instead of passing the function as argument since that is never invoked.

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe Thanks! That'll teach me for trying to answer questions on a hangover. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve this.

```
$scope.arealist = [];

$http.get('arealist.json').success(function (response) {
    $scope.arealist = response.map(function (data) {
        return data.area_name;
    });
});
```

[Browser support for map.](http://caniuse.com/#search=map)

If you are using libraries like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/), use _.map() for the same result.

```
$scope.arealist = [];

$http.get('arealist.json').success(function (response) {
    $scope.arealist = _.map(response, function (data) {
        return data.area_name;
    });
});
```